# How to prevent dhclient overwriting static addresses on network interface?

Tags: networking, dhclient

I have a `dhclient` running on `eno2` interface:

```
3070 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eno2.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eno2.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eno2.leases eno2
```

`dhclient` has got `10.10.10.48/25` lease from the DHCP server and installed it to `eno2`:

```
$ ip a sh dev eno2
7: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:1e:f8:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.48/25 brd 10.10.10.127 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3ea8:2aff:fe1e:f8db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$
```

This DHCP server leases addresses from `10.10.10.1` to `10.10.10.50`. I would like to add `10.10.10.55/25` to `eno2` interface while keeping the `dhclient` running. Is this possible? At the moment the `dhclient` seems to remove the manually added `10.10.10.55/25` address after a while. Most likely when the lease gets updated. I have no control over the DHCP server. Currently I'm running `while true; do sudo ip a add 10.10.10.55/25 dev eno2 2>/dev/null; done` as a workaround.

Comment: What is the problem you face? Why and how does adding the IP not work? Did you try adding the address in `/etc/networking/interfaces`?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, the workaround you give sets the IP you say the DHCP server gives and puts it on eno4.5, an interface you haven't mentioned anywhere else. You also appear to be a bit confused, an interface is either configured by DHCP or statically. If you have dhclient running on an interface you're asking for it to be configured by DHCP, but it appears you rather want to configure it statically. In that case, the solution is: stop dhclient.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I improved the question.

Comment: Now the question makes sense, and 5-10 years ago I knew what to do, but I'm pretty sure there have been changes in how this is done, but back in the day you would just add the static ip to a virtual interface/alias.